# Which verbs allow time words to come after?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

I notice some verbs like 会 and 将 among some others can be placed before time words.

Like in my sentence below, an example:

我将在十一点半给你打电话, 好的? - **Pinyin:** (Wǒ jiàng zài shíyī diǎn bàn gěi nǐ dǎ diànhuà, hǎo de?)

I've seen this many times and I'm wondering if it's just certain verbs that allow this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Time/date can be placed after the aux/modal verb which supports the main verb, to indicate the tense of the act, in the pattern of - **Aux/Modal Verb + 在 + Time + Main Verb**.

- 我"要"在十一點抵達 - I want/must/need to arrive at 11 o'clock.
- 我"能"在十一點抵達 - I can arrive at 11 o'clock.
- 我"將/會/將會"在十一點抵達/- I shall/will arrive at 11 o'clock.
- 我"必會"在十一點抵達 - I certainly will arrive at 11 o'clock.

Comment: Thank you for examples.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like in English.

The original sentence you gave was  我在十一点半给你打电话，好吗？（好的sounds weird,say 好吗）

将 means I'm going to; so adding it becomes:

"I'm going to call you at 11:30, alright?" 我将在十一点半给你打电话, 好吗?

会 means I will; so adding it becomes:  "I will call you at 11:30 alright?" 我会在十一点半给你打电话，好吗？

Now, you see the pattern right? Both indicate some time in which we would call the person. You can't randomly add verbs there, like run or jump; I run call you? Doesn't sound right, right?

On a side note, words like 立马，立即，赶紧 can also be added (indicating some kind of time, but because of the immediate urgency, adds a tone to the sentence); for instance, 赶紧在十一点半给我打电话，Call me at 11:30！(with some sentiment of anger within)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!